# Will my Cookie Clicker save last beyond a reboot?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I have been loathe to reboot my machine for risk my Cookie Clicker game would lose all its hard-won progress.

Am I being silly, here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're ever unsure, you can always export your game by going to the Menu and clicking "Export save". You will get a code which you can then use to import the same game.

Comment: True, but only necessary if the browser doesn't allow cookies

Answer (score 7):

Haidro's answer is the safest, but to answer the question, Yes, your save will normally survive a reboot because it is saved to a cookie (no pun intended). The save will not survive if the cookie is disallowed, which might happen on computers set to not use cookies, or if you are using something like incognito mode.

Cookies also normally will disappear after a period of time without visiting the website, typically 1 or 3 months. However, given the rate of updates and resets, thats probably not an issue in this case.

Comment: *"Cookies also normally will disappear after [..] typically 1 or 3 months"* - The website creator defines how long the cookie lasts.  They can have it last indefinitely, which would most likely be the case here.  You can check how long before a cookie for a site expires in the options of your browser *(eg. for Firefox, tools->options->privacy->"remove individual cookies")*.  Of course, the cookie will still be lost if you clear all your cookies, delete the user, reformat your computer etc.

Comment: Taking a quick browse through the well documented source code reveals that the author sets the expiration date on the save cookie for 5 years from your last visit :) I imagine that its more likely that you will lose your save from clearing your browser cookies than it actually expiring. `//that's right. we're using cookies. yeah I went there`